# Como comparar uma lista de valores numéricos com outra variável em Python

Tags: python

Preciso fazer uma função que compare os valores de uma lista com uma variável, retorne o valor da lista mais próximo ou igual ao valor da variável.

ex:A lista é lista = [1,2,3,7] e variável é v = 2. Nesse caso retorna o valor 2 da lista.

ex2: A lista é lista = [1,2,3,7] e a variável é v = 6. Nesse caso será retornado o valor 7 por ser o mais próximo.

Abaixo esta o meu código, calcula a média e compara o valor da média com a lista

```
def media(list):
som = 0
for item in list:
    som += item
med = som/len(list)
return med

def proxMed(list):
valor = 0
med = media(list)
for item in list:
    if item == trunc(med):
        valor = item
    else:
        while (med != item):
            med1 = med - 1
            med2 = med + 1
            if trunc(med1) == item:
                valor = item
                med = item
            if trunc(med2) == item:
                valor = item
                med = item
return valor
```

`list = [1,2,6,9,7,7,1]
print('A média é {:.2f}'.format(media(list)))
print('O valor mais proximo da média é {}'.format(proxMed(list)))`

Comment: Você irá sempre buscar pelo valor mais próximo à média ou esse valor de referência pode mudar? E o seu código funciona? Dá algum erro? Se sim, qual? Se não, produz o resultado esperado? Se não, qual resultado deu? Qual deveria dar?

Comment: Vou sempre buscar mais próximo à média e esse valor pode mudar. Apenas a função que calcula a média funciona. Sim, da erro lógico. Não aparece nada no segundo print, porque a função proxMed não funciona como o esperado.  Não aparece o segundo print quando o código é executado. Deveria aparece o valor da lista mais próximo ao valor da média

Comment: Eu não comentei na resposta o erro na sua solução por simplesmente não entender o que você tentou fazer, principalmente na lógica do `while` dentro do `for`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se você deseja buscar sempre o valor mais próximo da média, basta você calcular o desvio de cada valor da lista perante a média, isto é, a diferença entre ambos, e verificar qual valor resulta na menor diferença. Para isso, você pode gerar um dicionário que atua como um mapa relacionando o valor da lista e a diferença do mesmo perante a média. Esta solução é válida pois o que é interessante saber será apenas o valor e não sua posição na lista. Ou seja, se a lista possuir valores duplicados, não fará diferença qual deles será retornado.

Assim, definimos a função `closest_to_average`:

```
def closest_to_average(lst):

    """ Busca na lista o valor mais próximo da média.

    Parâmetros:
        lst list: Lista de números a ser verificada.

    Retorno:
        numérico: Valor mais próximo da média.
    """

    avg = sum(lst) / len(lst)
    diffs = {value: abs(value - avg) for value in lst}

    return min(diffs, key=diffs.get)
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/AFMap5) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/SurprisedRoundPerimeter)</sup>

Onde o valor da média obtemos calculando a soma dos termos da lista, dividindo pelo seu tamanho:

```
avg = sum(lst) / len(lst)
```

Também fazemos o mapa de relação entre os valores e o respectivo desvio perante à média:

```
diffs = {value: abs(value - avg) for value in lst}
```

Por fim, retornamos a chave do dicionário que está relacionada com o menor distância à média. Desta forma, fazendo:

```
print( closest_to_average([1,2,6,9,7,7,1]) ) # 6
```

Teríamos o resultado `6`, pois a média será igual a `4.714285714285714` e a relação de cada valor com a diferença será:

```
{
  1: 3.7142857142857144, 
  2: 2.7142857142857144, 
  6: 1.2857142857142856, 
  9: 4.285714285714286, 
  7: 2.2857142857142856
}
```

Onde é possível confirmar visualmente que o `6` é o valor que possui menor diferença. Repare também que o dicionário possuirá apenas uma chave igual a `1` e outra igual a `7`, mesmo possuindo esses valores repetidos na lista, como já comentado no início da resposta.

Comment: Belo código e ótima resposta.

Comment: muito obrigado. Sou iniciante nessa linguagem e tem muita coisa que estou aprendendo ainda. A propósito  se puder me explicar ou indicar um artigo para entender essa sintaxe melhor (diffs = {value: abs(value - avg) for value in lst}) eu entendi a lógica mas acho que preciso me habituar mais com esse tipo de estrutura.

Comment: @CarlosStorari O nome disso, em inglês, é [*dict comprehension*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/), caso queira pesquisar sobre. Gerará um dicionário com o resultado da expressão entre chaves. A expressão percorre a lista de números com o `for value in lst` e para cada valor analisa a expressão à esquerda: `value: abs(value - avg)`, onde o primeiro `value` definirá a chave do dicionário e o resultado de `abs()` o respectivo valor.